# Vertical menu with stacked text

Tags: html, css

I have created a fixed vertical menu with stacked text [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x23yg9ot/1/)

Each of my sections will be 100% height.  I wasn't sure if this is the correct way to do things, but I essentially used `span` elements and set them to be `display: block;`

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="#header">
    <span> H </span>
    <span> O </span>
    <span> M </span>
    <span> E </span>
</a>
```

Now what I have kind of works, but seeing as I am dealing with 100% heights for each section, I am trying to place the menu vertically aligned within the middle of the container.  I have tried using this property on the `ul` but it does not move the whole menu into the middle.

I was thinking about using a margin top of 50%, but if I add more items to the menu this may not work.  Additionally, if I did add more items to the menu, is there a way of ensuring that the whole menu is displayed within the viewport, so not overlapping into another section?  I have updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x23yg9ot/2/) to demonstrate what I mean.  Because I have added another couple of menu items to the menu, test2 seems to disappear because it does not fit into the viewport.  Is there a way I can avoid this?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox for it. You just have to add 100% height for your `.navbar` element and the following settings for `.navbar-nav`:

```
.navbar-nav {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n4p9hknu/2/

If there are more menu list items than fit on the page, `flex: wrap` will cause them to wrap into  a second column: https://jsfiddle.net/rubgowpa/1/

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `height: 100%` from `.nav.navbar-nav`
2. Set `position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` on `.nav.navbar-nav`
3. (Optional) add a height-based media query to handle the menu's display on screens which will not be big enough to fit the menu options when displayed vertically.

HTML (unchanged):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-left">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#header">
                <span> H </span>
                <span> O </span>
                <span> M </span>
                <span> E </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">
                <span> A </span>
                <span> B </span>
                <span> O </span>
                <span> U </span>
                <span> T </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">
                <span> C </span>
                <span> O </span>
                <span> N </span>
                <span> T </span>
                <span> A </span>
                <span> C </span>
                <span> T </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<header id="header">
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="header-content-inner">
      <h1 id="homeHeading">
        Some Title
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="bg-primary" id="about"></section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    background: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

header .header-content {
    padding: 0 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 46px;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-left {
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    width: 139px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a > span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#about {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media (min-height: 450px){
  .navbar-nav > li > a > span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/x23yg9ot/5/

---

You will obviously want to adjust the height condition in the media query to suit your needs.

This adjustment could be done automatically using JavaScript, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/x23yg9ot/8/

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code using *flex*

```
<style>
.page-scroll{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="#">
    <span> H </span>
    <span> O </span>
    <span> M </span>
    <span> E </span>
</a>
```